# how to add the " via domain" in the php mailer "From" property when sending email?

Tags: php, phpmailer

i want my recipient to receive an email, with a "FROM", like this format

```
sasori <sasori@blablah.com> via blahblah.com
```

the question is, how to add that "via blahblah.com" when php mailer's "from" property is only accepting an email address..it throws an error if I concatenate the " via blablah.com "

Comment: Are you using PHP Mailer library ? or PHP simple mail function ?

Comment: I think the `via` clause is added by some servers automatically when the domain in the address is not the same as the domain of the machine. It's not something done by the application.

Comment: php mailer library, not the simple mail func

Comment: Have a look at the headers ("view source"/"view original" in your mail client) of an e-mail that displays how you want, and see how it's done there. Perhaps it's a `Sender:` header?

Comment: need some precise answer about this issue